# bootstrapvalidator Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'group' of undefined

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have this same issue as described here: [bootstrapvalidator gives "Cannot read property 'group' of undefined" on ckeditor field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620475/bootstrapvalidator-gives-cannot-read-property-group-of-undefined-on-ckeditor), except it is not related to ckeditor. The validation code is taken from here: http://formvalidation.io/validators/identical/ 
Here is my jquery code:

```
    $('form').bootstrapValidator({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            password2: {
                validators: {
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 6,
                        max: 10,
                        message: 'Field must be 6 to 10 characters long'
                    },
                    identical: {
                        field: 'password1',
                        message: 'The password and its confirm are not the same'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

And here is the html:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="password" name="password1" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Repeat password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="password" name="password2" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
```

I'm completely stack here. Please someone help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I doubleread documentation. Apparently the way I was using this validator is wrong because documentation is for newer (paid) version but I have older free version of bootstrapvalidator. The syntax of this validator in old version is different:

```
            password1: {
                validators: {
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 6,
                        max: 10,
                        message: 'Field must be 6 to 10 characters long'
                    },
                    identical: {
                        field: 'password2',
                        message: 'The password and its confirm are not the same'
                    }
                }
            },
            password2: {
                validators: {
                    identical: {
                        field: 'password1',
                        message: 'The password and its confirm are not the same'
                    }
                }
            }
```

So, script must include both checked fields.